# How can one go about recognizing a kind of motion using 3D depth data?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm using a Kinect device, and I'm currently extracting Joints, and Depth data unto probably a buffer data of 15 frames. This is done at 30 frames per second.

The whole point of it is to try and recognize an arm motion, like a punches.

What I currently have in mind is have a multidimensional feature vector of 15 frames x {joints, depth data}, or possibly even calculate an optical flow for a sparse feature set using the iterative Lucas-Kanade method with pyramids to reduce it to 14 frames x{joints, depth data}

Then maybe apply a PCA, but I'm not sure what kind of classifier to use, and if I use a neural network how to build one to train it

Any advice?

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel when there is a large body of research? [Here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167865513000500) is a recent survey ([preprint](http://files.is.tue.mpg.de/jgall/tutorials/slides/motionanalysis_DRAFT.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks for the article, hoping I can use currently built wheel to assemble this car, but I'm not sure where I can find them. Based on page 17's table, HON4D, DMM-HOG, 4d Local SpatioTemporal Features, STOP, and ROP all seem viable for the feature extraction step. Do I need to re-implement them, or do they actually exist as reusable blocks of code?

Comment: I don't know; search the students' home pages, and github/bitbucket. [Here's one](http://yangxd.org/code/) to get you started.

Comment: @Emre the survey in that link is an acceptable answer. Just finished my project, and had a good sense of direction thanks to Qing's article. The latter link didn't really have DMM-HOG example, but I ended up implementing one in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll save yourself time by [surveying the literature](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167865513000500) ([preprint](http://files.is.tue.mpg.de/jgall/tutorials/slides/motionanalysis_DRAFT.pdf)), rather than inventing a new algorithm, which will likely be no better. Abstract:

> Analysis of human behaviour through visual information has been a highly active research topic in the computer vision community. This was previously achieved via images from a conventional camera, however recently depth sensors have made a new type of data available. This survey starts by explaining the advantages of depth imagery, then describes the new sensors that are available to obtain it. In particular, the Microsoft Kinect has made high-resolution real-time depth cheaply available. The main published research on the use of depth imagery for analysing human activity is reviewed. Much of the existing work focuses on body part detection and pose estimation. A growing research area addresses the recognition of human actions. The publicly available datasets that include depth imagery are listed, as are the software libraries that can acquire it from a sensor. This survey concludes by summarising the current state of work on this topic, and pointing out promising future research directions. For both researchers and practitioners who are familiar with this topic and those who are new to this field, the review will aid in the selection, and development, of algorithms using depth data.

You may also find [this code](http://yangxd.org/code/) helpful.